# Javascript not working with JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm working on a jsf page and I'm trying to program a button onclick event by javascript to be able to add rows dynamically in a jsf dataTable ; but the problem is that jsf is not loading javascript code anymore
I tried to use an external js file

```
      <h:outputScript name="">
```

and also tried using the  tag
Any suggestions please ? Thanks!

Comment: Not loading anymore, so it did before. Find the things you changed and fix them

Answer (score 2):

You can use either JSF `<h:outputScript>` or html `<script>` tag.

First, you need to create a folder under WebContent and name it as resources. Under resources folder, you can create folders where you want to put your resources such as CSS, javascript, images etc.

For JSF `<h:outputScript>`:

```
<h:outputScript library="script" name="/script.js"</h:outputScript>
```

Where the value of the library is the name of the folder which contains your javascript file.

Here's the code for HTML `<script>`:

```
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/script/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried to do that but the same probleme is genereted

Comment: Check your browser first, you might have disabled javascript